# Wrapping Html with Json Data

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, accordion

The problem I encountered is after execution, the page will not get the json data, the page will show the following as string. But all my web  api service successfully get the data.

```
{{recipe.Name}}
{{recipe.desc}}
{{recipe.allergen}}
{{recipe.cost}}
```

My HTML :

```
<accordion  close-others="false" >
  <div>
    <accordion-group  class="div-recipe-header">
      <accordion-heading></accordion-heading> 
      <div class="inner"></div> 
    </accordion-group>
  </div>
</accordion>
```

My JavaScript to wrap

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    aa = global.userhtml// handles the UserHtml Data in Json return
    $(".inner").wrapAll(aa)
  })
</script>
```

Sample JSON Data:

```
{
  ID: "0908",
  UserHtml: "<table ><tbody><trclass="recipe-list" data-ng-repeat="recipe in
                      recipe_data" ng-if="recipe.Keyword == keyw.Keyword" ><td><center>
                       <span id="img{{recipe.ID}}X"><a id="{{recipe.ID}}"  href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <img  ng-if="recipe.ID !=='" fallback-src="images/default.png" ng-src="
                         {{recipe.Pictures}}" class="images" id="img{{recipe.ID}}"/> <div class="div-recipe- 
                          allergen">{{recipe.allergen}}</div><div class="div-recipe-cost">{{recipe.cost}}
                         </div></td></tr></tbody></table>"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KOqwCFTD4aeaCsumRdom?p=preview

```
// DISCLAIMER: This is EXTREMELY DIRTY, it "works" but have many potential issues 
// (depending what you are trying to do with it which has not been stated at all in the question)

var myglobal = {
  userhtml: '<table><tbody><tr class="recipe-list" ng-repeat="recipe in recipe_data" ng-if="recipe.Keyword == keyw.Keyword" ><td><center><span id="img{{recipe.ID}}X"><a id="{{recipe.ID}}"  href="javascript:void(0);">'+
            '<img  ng-if="recipe.ID !==\'\'" fallback-src="images/default.png" ng-src="{{recipe.Pictures}}" class="images" id="img{{recipe.ID}}"/> <div class="div-recipeallergen">{{recipe.allergen}}</div><div class="div-recipe-cost">{{recipe.cost}}</div></td></tr></tbody></table>',

  recipe_data: [  { ID: '1234', Pictures:'/picture.jpeg', 
                    Keyword: 'food', allergen:'peanuts', cost:'5$' }, 
                  { ID: '1235', Pictures:'/picture.jpeg', 
                    Keyword: 'food', allergen:'kiwi', cost:'10$' } ]
};


var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive("myUserHtml", ['$compile', function($compile){

  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // Extremely dirty hack!
      scope.myglobal = myglobal;
      scope.recipe_data = myglobal.recipe_data;
      scope.keyw = {Keyword:"food"};

      scope.$watch('myglobal.userhtml', function() {
        element.html(scope.myglobal.userhtml);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      });      
    }
  };

}]);
```

the HTML has been modified (notice the my-user-html class: this is the class that triggers the directive defined above (matches the name `myUserHtml`).

```
<accordion close-others="false">
  <div>
    <accordion-group class="div-recipe-header">
      <accordion-heading></accordion-heading>
      <div class="inner my-user-html"></div>
    </accordion-group>
  </div>
</accordion>
```

I changed the "data-ng-repeat" to "ng-repeat". I suspect your server side code does not properly handle two single quotes in a row (and converts it to a single single quote).  I added backslashes so it reads `recipe.ID !==\'\'` -- this is properly escaped so the end result HTML is just `recipe.ID !==''`

What language are you using on the server to generate that JSON? (or better yet show us the source code!!) It is not escaping the string properly for JSON. Use tools or libraries to build a json document DO NOT USE string concatenation if you do not understand what is going on.

@KeenEgs jasonSCript is right, your javascript string is badly corrupted. It is more than "changing single quote to double quote" and changing "double quotes to single quotes". Javascript and HTML support either single quote or double quotes. If you try to "nest" a string inside another string, you have to be extra careful. You have to really understand this concept to be successful in programming.

var a = "abcd";  // valid string - normal

var a = "ab"cd";   // this is INVALID the quote in the middle will end the string leaving  cd"; as being invalid javascript.

var a = "ab\"cd";  // this is valid: A "backslash" \ is used to signify that the next character is part of the string and is not meant to terminate the string.

var a = 'ab"cd';   // this is valid: different quotes are used so it does not get confused.

Since your template includes strings (and I also saw a single quote in there) you have to be extra extra careful.  You might even end up having 3 levels: strings inside strings inside strings!

Comment: So the JSON data contains an Angular template? For this to work, you need to make sure it gets compiled! (Using the $compile service). Angular does this automatically normally, but not when you are inserting DOM nodes using jquery like your call to $().wrapAll(html).

Comment: You also have a typo in global.userhtml  (it does not match UserHtml) case.  Unless this is not referring to the same object.

Comment: now the problem is my global variable userhtml is 'undefined' but using console.log in other js file its has a value

Comment: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$compile' is undefined

Comment: You should give out more of your source or build a jsfiddle because you have errors that is extremely difficult to fix without imagining what type of stuff you are doing. You seem to lack quite a few basic knowledge.  As the other fellow said $compile is an Angular service, you can't just "call it" out of nowhere.

Comment: Can I put the compile in a global variable ?

Comment: The compile has two steps, the second requires a "scope" to work. Else it will not work.

Could you explain at a higher level, what you are trying to do?  All of this is quite strange I must admit. It feels like a JQuery-style page where you are trying to "strap on" a little bit of Angular in the middle of the page -- using dynamically provided HTML templates.

Comment: Your solution help me. one thing is not yet done. one the part of pictures . Angular error  because of the quote.. if ng-if="recipe.ID !==\'\' - because since my data will come from database SQL sErver. I cannot insert backslash.. in insert statement

Comment: Why do you say you cannot put a backslash in SQL Server?  Backslashes are a valid character and are actually required in some cases. Which portion of the "SQL Server database" does not allow you to type in backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is invalid. You are ending your string quotes early

```
{
  ID: "0908",
  UserHtml: "<table ><tbody><trclass="..... <- You're closing your quotes here
}
```

Try using single quotes instead

```
{
  ID: "0908",
  UserHtml: '<table ><tbody><trclass="..etc..."
            |                        ^ double quotes for html within JSON string
            ^ single quotes around JSON object
}
```

Also make sure that you don't include any new lines.

I recommend checking JSON lint sites like http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON

Comment: I need to change Double quotes by single quote ? and Single to Double quote?

Comment: my Json is valid according to the link you gave for validtaion

Answer (score 0):

I the other answers may be correct about the json string formatting, but your biggest hurdle is that you can't just treat an incoming html string as a template for Angular unless you compile it first. Try doing this before using the html segment:

```
global.userhtml = $compile(global.userhtml)($scope);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. where will I put it ? in what area?

Comment: Just before you insert it into the DOM with `$(".inner").wrapAll(global.userhtml)`.

Comment: now the problem is my global variable userhtml is 'undefined' but using console.log in other js file its has a value

Comment: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$compile' is undefined

Comment: Yes, `$compile` is actually service that Angular will inject into your controller if requested. You can read up on Angular dependency injection here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: And, just to be clear, **all** of this (including the DOM insertion) would need to happen inside of your Angular controller, in a context that has access to `$scope`, injected services, etc.